# Publish report for maven compiler plugin xlint

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I would like to capture warnings/errors generated by maven-compiler-plugin (when running compile goal) and output them to a file (be it xml or json).By default, maven-compiler-plugin doesn't provide the option to configure a reporter. So, curious to know how this can be done. Here's my plugin config -

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <compilerArgs>
        <arg>-verbose</arg>
        <arg>-Xlint:all,-options,-path</arg>
      </compilerArgs>
      <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Where does you build run?

Comment: My build is running on azure pipeline

Comment: The simplest solution would be to collect the log output... because the maven-compiler-plugin does have any kind of reporting output neither in xml, json or alike...